# read block indefinitely for file on CIFS and Samba

Tags: go, kubernetes, cifs

Our on production system we have mounted the Azure file share using the CIFS (using kubernetes).

For certain files, we see our program block on reading indefinitely. Our application stack is golang. Hence sharing the golang script.

A sample script to read the affected file 10 bytes at a time eventual hang

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "time"
)
func main() {
    handler, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() {
        err := handler.Close()
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }()
    var totalBytes int64
    var totalCounter int64 = 0
    for {
        d := make([]byte, 10)
        // bufio.NewReader(handler).Read
        // 2147483647
        // 3461194000
        n, err := handler.Read(d)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            panic(err)
        }
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("EOF received")
            break
        }
        totalBytes += int64(n)
        if (n != 0) && (totalCounter%10000000) == 0 {
            kb := totalBytes / 1024
            mb := kb / 1024
            gb := mb / 1024
            fmt.Println(time.Now())
            fmt.Printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", totalCounter, totalBytes, kb, mb, gb)
            totalCounter = 0
        }
        totalCounter++
        if (totalBytes / 1024) >= 3461180 {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", d)
        }
    }
}
```

We have are read blocked on certain files indefinitely as if the EOF was never seen.

Here the stack trace obtained after SIGSEGV was triggered

```
SIGSEGV: segmentation violation
PC=0x45d1e1 m=0 sigcode=0
goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime.futex()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:519 +0x21
runtime.futexsleep(0xc000022000, 0xdbbbfe30, 0x421831)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/os_linux.go:44 +0x36
runtime.notesleep(0x53ccb0)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:160 +0x87
runtime.mPark()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:1441 +0x2a
runtime.stopm()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:2408 +0x78
runtime.findrunnable()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:2984 +0x865
runtime.schedule()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:3367 +0x239
runtime.park_m(0xc000001380)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:3516 +0x14d
runtime.mcall()
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:307 +0x43
goroutine 1 [syscall, 40 minutes]:
syscall.Syscall(0x0, 0x3, 0xc000256430, 0xa)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s:20 +0x5
syscall.read(0xc0000b6120, {0xc000256430, 0x7f6604197ce0, 0x5})
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go:687 +0x4d
syscall.Read(...)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go:189
internal/poll.ignoringEINTRIO(...)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:582
internal/poll.(*FD).Read(0xc0000b6120, {0xc000256430, 0xa, 0xa})
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:163 +0x285
os.(*File).read(...)
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/os/file_posix.go:32
os.(*File).Read(0xc0000b4018, {0xc000256430, 0xa, 0xa})
/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.17.2/libexec/src/os/file.go:119 +0x5e
main.main()
/Users/admin/Documents/goProject/src/github.com/ringsq/detech-eof.go:22 +0xb6
```

Update: I tested the same script with the same file on. a dedicated VM all is good. After which I ran the same script with the same file inside the container and the result was the script just blocked.

Comment: What does the segfault have to do with the blocking read? If `Read` is blocking, that is outside of the control of the Go program.

Comment: The application is running under the container under non-privileged mode(I realise this after I sent the SIGSEGV signal as I wanted core dump) I have just shared it over here because with reflect that go scheduler is waiting on syscall READ.

Comment: I think you are just going to have to do some more debugging of your system, since the code itself (aside from the slightly incorrect `Read` handling) is not going to result in a blocked application (unless of course the underlying FD were to block, like in a pipe for example). Try a container with more privileges, try without a container, try a different kernel, try reading directly with syscalls, and so on.

Comment: @JimB I tried your suggestion I tested the above script on a dedicated VM with mounted Azure file share no problem there same file same script on container still block.